# Look from a moving camera to a fix point opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

My camera is place on a moving object, but it always be pointed to a point in scene. How can I do that? How can I calculate the perpendiculars? How, if the position of the observator always moves, the direction stay focused on that point?

Comment: That's more math than C++. Check out your linear algebra courses, everything must be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My camera is place on a moving object, but it always be pointed to a point in scene. How can I do that?  How, if the position of the observator [sic] always moves, the direction stay focused on that point?

[`gluLookAt()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml).

> How can I calculate the perpendiculars?

[Cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: Cross-product between who? I have only the coordonates of the moving object and the fix object. I work with my camera using position vector, who at me is the position of moving object, forward who i don't know who it is, up and right. At gluLookAt the 4,5,6 parameters i think there are from this Cross-Product, but I don't know between who to make it. Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OpenGL are you using. This depends a lot on which environment you are working on. If you are in OpenGL ES you need to do it yourself, otherwise you can achieve the wanted result by playing with glLookat. Let us know.

Comment: I solved the problem by setting the position vector with the coordinates of the moving object and the forward vector with the difference between the center of the static object and the position vector, and the up vector with the values 0.0, 1.0, 0.0. I don't know the version of opengl I use. I didn't known that there are versions:).